# Array fill with the Id´s of a SELECT

Tags: php

I have to make an array with the POSTED value of one SELECT.   The SELECT selects the products ONE BY ONE. First I choose one product and POST it then another product and I POST the SECOND ONE and so on.....
I want to create an array of the ID of the products that are posted by the SELECT but this array has to grow while I introduce more and more products.

I have use this but It makes the array with only the last product I have choosen.

```
foreach($_POST['idproducto'] as $key => $val) {
$cadenaides = $cadenaides . "$val,";
}
$cadenaides = $cadenaides . 1;
```

I would like the array to have all the ID of the products I choose ONE BY ONE in the SELECT.

Comment: i wish you knew what you were talking about

Comment: really bad description. if I understand correctly you want an HTML dropdown box that will select products, one after another, and a JS/jQuery that will add the selected product to the rest of the selected products. If that's correct than you should re-tag this question as Javascript/jQuery and remove the PHP tag - doing something like this on the server-side is a really bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you want to assign a number to each posted value. You can do this like so:

```
foreach(...) {
    $cadenaides[] = $val;
}
```

Your values will the be stored in an array. You can check your array with `print_r($cadenaides);`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments above and assuming that you use MySQL I would suggest the following:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_producto SEPARATOR ',') FROM producto WHERE .... put your conditions here ..;`

This will concatinate all IDs in a single string like that `1,2,3,5,8,9...` in a single result, after that you can do just one POST request. Very usefull in many cases BTW.

The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable, which has a default value of 1024. Could be very large - max: `4294967295` for `32-bit` system.